# 100vh not making image 100% of viewport

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to use `100vh` to make a `background-image` always have a height per the size of the screen. What I am wanting to do is use the same image for each viewport and allow the `overflow: hidden` to make due of the access width. In essence, narrowing the image more vertically. However, my attempt is not working. The `background-image` is not adjusting to the 100vh.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```css
#home-cover1 {
 background-image: url("/images/home-cover1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#home-cover1-wrap {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-cover1">
  <div id="home-cover1-wrap">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change CSS I think background-size: cover; is Best

```
#home-cover1 {
    background-image: url("https://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/home-cover1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I added `background-position:center` as well and it looks great. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your #home-cover1 **background-size** lack the 100% of height, change `background-size: 100%;` to `background-size: 100% 100%;`